# VB.NET Moving Objects Diagonally using Keys

Tags: vb.net

How can I Move objects diagonally when two directional keys are pressed? How to do that?
I tried adding elseif statement for Handling Up and Right together but It still move up or right when i press them together

```
  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X + 5, Label1.Location.Y)

    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X - 5, Label1.Location.Y)

    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y + 5)

    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Label1.Location.Y - 5)

    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up And e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X + 5, Label1.Location.Y + 5)
    End If

    CheckIntersections()
    If Label1.Location.Y < 0 Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Me.Height)
    ElseIf Label1.Location.Y > Me.Height Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Label1.Location.X, Me.Bottom = 0)
    ElseIf Label1.Location.X < 0 Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(Me.Width, Label1.Location.Y)
    ElseIf Label1.Location.X > Me.Width Then
        Label1.Location = New Point(0, Label1.Location.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `KeyDown` event occurs each time a single key is pressed. Therefore you'll need to remember when a cursor key is pressed on once occurrence of `KeyDown` to check in another occurrence for another cursor key being pressed.

Remember to subscribe to `KeyUp` events to clear the state because the use could press one cursor key, release it and then press another.

Your code will never work:

> ```
> ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Up And e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
> ```

because this cannot be true. `KeyCode` is a single key code, it cannot be both one key and another.

Comment: can you code the diagonal movement of the object when two cursor keys are pressed?

Comment: @XtraCode Not any time soon (I'm away from my development system).